# Howto Write normal sentence in SQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to write this sentence for DQL :

```
SELECT id FROM `article` WHERE `created_at` IN (select max(created_at) from article)
```

I try this one but i have some error :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.id')
            ->where('p.createdAt IN (select max(p.createdAt)from p)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Error :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 88 near 'p)': Error: Class 'p' is not defined.
```

Thanks a lot,
ibynmax

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to write out the subquery in the query builder:

```
$subQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('max(p.createdAt)');

$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

return $queryBuilder
    ->select('p.id')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('p.createdAt', $subQuery->getDQL()))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```